# Is there a way to remove file path in VSCode test explorer?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, flutter-test

When I use test explorer in VSCode, it shows my files with the file path:
Example

[image: example]

Is there a way to hide the file path and show only the file name?

I'm using Flutter and Dart extensions.

I've search a lot a didn't find nothing that helps me, but in this course that I'm watching, his VSCode shows only the file name: Example

[image: example]

Comment: hi, I am facing the same issue. did you found the solution ??

Comment: @Srinadh Unfortunately no, still the same way

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to de-clutter the bar, this might help.

In the Test Explorer tab, click on the three dots on the right side:
[image: Test Explorer tab]

From there, choose "View as List" at the bottom:

[image: Test Explorer options]

Comment: Your solution removes the grouping while only showing the test names. 
For reference .. That test explorer view in question is coming from resocoder flutter tutorials..